# are laptop webcams 360 degree?

Tags: laptop, webcam, dell-latitude

I have a question. are enterprise model laptop's (Dell Latitude) webcams 360 degree? (specifically but anyway any vendor) I got a refurbished one, but official Windows app, not 360 capture anyway
But I have doubts.

Are nonmoving(fixated) webcams on usual upper center, modified to become 360 or does lens has to move making it not possible for so? Also can entire monitor exploited to become a panoramic 360 / few 360 combined camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

360° picture requires a device which can "see" all directions.

That can be either a rotating camera, special mirrors or multiple cameras. None of them fit within a laptop monitor, therefore they can't make 360° pictures. (Without moving the laptop itself).

Comment: How does CC cameras that are one corner of room work? Can they see 360 degree? Can rotating camera placed inside normal shape size laptop webcam slot, but since laptop shape is rectangle, could they get visual?

Comment: Seems we've different understanding of 360° pictures. I mean it like this:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnidirectional_camera . So 360° camera in a corner doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Aoi. T_015, a camera in the corner of a rectangular room has nothing over 90° to see.  A camera in the center of the ceiling can see a 360° view of the floor (a circle around the floor), but not 360° relative to the camera, itself (what's behind the camera).